# Cannot set env variables when ssh a network machine

Tags: ros, ssh, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set up a network configuration between two machines. I already did all the steps mentioned in the ROS tutorials. This is my setup:

In PC1:

```
roscore
export ROS_MASTER_URI=https://${PC1_hostname}:11311
rosrun <package> <node>
```

In PC2:

```
export ROS_IP="$(ifconfig | perl -nle'/dr:(10\.85\.167\.\S+)/ && print $1')"
export ROS_HOSTNAME="<PC2_hostname>"
export ROS_MASTER_URI=https://${PC1_hostname}:11311
rosrun <package> <node>
```

I can trasmit data back and forth between the two machines using ROS.

Now, I want to start PC2 from PC1 using a launch file. ROS indeed get the connection from PC1 to PC2, but then the program fails when trying to run the node. I found that the error is because ROS is `ssh`-ing into PC2, and ssh does not allow to set environment variables, which means ROS was never sourced and there isn't any environment variables. My `env.sh` file is right since if I run the script locally it works.

I found this on the web, I tried some of the solutions with no success.

[ssh environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

How to allow environment variables to be set when ssh into an external PC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186100/cannot-set-env-variables-when-ssh-a-network-machine/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2014-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-11**:
Environment variables must be set when you ssh into another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the machine tag in your launch file, you need to specify the env-loader parameter. See: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine#Examples

Note that the requirements for the env-loader script are fairly strict. It should:

- Be executable. ( run `chmod a+x` on it, and make sure the first line is `#!/bin/bash` )
- Source ROS.
- Set your other environment variables, such as ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP
- The last line **MUST** be `exec "$@"`

If you're still having trouble, please **EDIT** your question to include your launch file and the exact console output you get from trying launch it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on 2014-07-11**:
This works!!! I had to put `exec "$@"` at the end of the `env.sh` file.